# 151 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of null, when removing 2nd expense element

Tags: javascript

Uncaught Type Error Cannot read property parent Node of null, 
when removing 2nd expense element, 
can you please help me solve this issue, 
I am unable to understand why this is happening, 
tried solving seeing various solutions on the internet, 
but not successful.

I add the amount and reason then click on expense the expense is added,
then when I try to remove expense by clicking on x button that specific expense element is removed when I try to remove 2nd element I get this error: 151 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of null, when removing 2nd expense element

```html
<body>
<div id="p1">
  <center>
    <h3>Total Budget</h3>
    <p id="bud">0</p> <br>
    <div id="dti">
      <P id="dec1">Income</P>
      <p id="decp">0</p>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="dte">
      <P id="dec1">Expense</P>
      <p id="decm">0</p>
    </div>
  </center>
</div>
<div id="p2">
  <center>
    <form name="f1" id="f1">
      <input type="text" name="reason" id="reason" placeholder="Reason" style="width: 200px; height: 30px;" >
      <input type="text" name="amount" id="amount" placeholder="Amount" style="width: 100px; height: 30px;">
      <input type="button" value="Income" onclick="inc()"  style="width: 100px; height: 30px;">
      <input type="button" value="Expense" onclick="exp()" style="width: 100px; height: 30px;">
    </form>
  </center>
</div>
<div id="p3">
  <div id="in">
    <br>
    <center>
      <h3>Income Details</h3>
    </center>
    <br>
  </div>
  <div id="ex">
    <br>
    <center>
      <h3>Expense Details</h3>
    </center>
    <br>
  </div>

  <script>
    var r=0, a=0, z=0, x=0, l=0,m=0,n=0, g=0,h=0, i=0, add=0, sub=0, newadd=0, newsub=0,mkkt=0, mkt=0, tkt=0;

    function inc(){
      r=f1.reason.value;
      a=f1.amount.value;
      clr();
      updatedi();
      budget();
      addinc();

    }

    function exp(){
      r=f1.reason.value;
      a=f1.amount.value;
      clr();
      updatede();
      budget();
      addexp();
    }

    function clr(){
      f1.reason.value=""
      f1.amount.value=""
    }

    function updatedi(){
      z +=parseInt(a);

      document.getElementById("decp").textContent=z;
    }

    function updatede(){
      x +=parseInt(a);

      document.getElementById("decm").textContent=x;
    }

    function budget(){
      l=document.getElementById('decp').textContent;
      m=document.getElementById('decm').textContent;
      n=l-m;
      document.getElementById('bud').textContent=n;

    }

    function addinc(){

      add='<div id="ii"><p id="pin1">addincv</p><p id="pin2">i0</p></div>'
      newadd=add.replace('addincv',r);
      newadd=newadd.replace('i0',a);
      document.getElementById("in").insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',newadd);

    }

    function addexp(){
      sub='<div id="ee" class="exp1"><p id="pex1">addexpv</p>  <form><input type="button" id="b1" onclick="rett(this.id);" value="x"></form>  <p id="pex2" class="expv1">e0</p> </div>'

      g+=1;
      h='e'+g;
      i='ev'+g;

      newsub=sub.replace('addexpv',r);
      newsub=newsub.replace('e0',a);
      newsub=newsub.replace('exp1',h);
      newsub=newsub.replace('expv1',i);
      document.getElementById("ex").insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',newsub);

    }

    function rett(a){
      mkkt=a;
      console.log(mkkt);
      mkt= mkkt.substring(1,mkkt.length)
      console.log(mkt)

      var elem = document.querySelector('.e1');
      
      elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there are several critical problems in your code and we should fix them before continuing to the solution. You are adding expense sections with the same id.

```
<div id="ee" class="e1">
<div id="ee" class="e2">
```

However, id's should be unique in the DOM. And then, you can easily remove elements by their id's. So in your `addexp` function, change the following line:

```
newsub=newsub.replace('ee',h);
```

By doing this, your generated class names (e1, e2, e3..) will become the unique id's of the elements.
Now in the remove function, you can access the element by its specific id and remove it. However, you click on the button, but you need to access the its containter's id. So pass the whole element as the parameter:

```
onclick="rett(this);
```

Modify the rett function as follows:

```
function rett(a){
  mkkt=a.parentNode.parentNode.id;
  console.log(mkkt);
  mkt= mkkt.substring(1,mkkt.length)
  console.log(mkt)


  var elem = document.querySelector("#" + mkkt);
  elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);    
 }
```

This function now basically does the following:
Since the element you want to remove is the container of the form that the input is in, you need to access two level parents up, and remove that element. Therefore `a.parentNode.parentNode.id` notation will get you that id.
The query selector should be parametric too. It had a static e1 parameter before. Now it's changed to the dynamic id.

The general solution is as explained above. You should also not forget to add your null and undefined controls too.